# d3.js Time Scale Chart, Array object values isnt rendering the chart whereas static values render the chart perfectly

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, d3.js, svg

Dynamically creating a Array with N objects from a json File

```
    var taskArray = [];


 d3.json("input.json", function(error, json) {
        if (error)
            return console.warn(error);

        for ( var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

                //console.log(json[i][0]);
                var tasks = [];
                var version = json[i][1];
                var phase = json[i][2];
                var part = version + "(" + phase + ")";
                var name = json[i][0];


                taskArray[i]={
                    "task" : part,
                    "type" : name,
                    "startTime" : json[i][3],
                    "endTime" : json[i][4]
                };

//      console.log(taskArray);
        }

        });
```

JSON file Format :

[["abc","abc_15.0.1","Intital_phase","Tue Jul 26 21:00:00 2016","Thu Jul 28 09:00:00 2016"]]

If I give the Array values Statically, It works :

```
  var taskArray = [

{
    task: "abc_15.0.1 (Intital_phase) ",
    type: "abc",
    startTime: "Mon Aug 01 06:00:00 2016", //year/month/day
    endTime: "Mon Aug 01 14:00:00 2016",
},
];

var dateFormat = d3.time.format("%a %b %e %H:%M:%S %Y");

var timeScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([d3.min(taskArray, function(d) {return dateFormat.parse(d.startTime);}),
                 d3.max(taskArray, function(d) {return dateFormat.parse(d.endTime);})])
        .range([0,w]);
```

Is the Array object not proper ? or the way i am accessing the object values is wrong, i am unable to find it.

Comment: Would you mind creating a minimal, runnable example?

Answer (score 1):

The D3 date parser returns a string, whereas you want to pass actual `Date` objects. Consider this:

```
var timeScale = d3.time.scale()
        .domain([d3.min(taskArray, function(d) {return new Date(d.startTime);}),
                 d3.max(taskArray, function(d) {return new Date(d.endTime);})])
        .range([0,w]);
```

**EDIT: found the reason!**

You are filling your `taskArray` inside `d3.json()` and trying to use it afterwards. This is not possible, because `d3.json()` is **asynchronous**. It returns immediately and does its job in background. That said you need to pass `d3.json()` a second parameter: a callback function. This function is called when the requested JSON file has been loaded. Long story short: move all code that relies on the data into a function that you pass as callback.

Comment: But what's the difference? The OP is using a string in his static array and, according to her/him, it's working.

Comment: For me this solves the issue with D3 v3. D3 v4 needs timeFormat instead of time.format and scaleTime instead of time.scale.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, is it possible, that d3.json automatically casts them to Date, if they match the format?

Comment: That's not the point. The point is: according to the OP the last snippet, with those values as strings and with that scale, is working.

Comment: Now that I read the question one more time, I think @GerardoFurtado might be right. But we will only know if the OP shows more code (running example or at least the full code)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGwmxR?editors=1111 here is a sample with the static data working but the problem is with dynamic data , can you look into this

Comment: @user3300373 would you mind including the not working dynamic data code?

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak i have added the code which retrieves data from json file into an Array, commented the Static Data:

JSON file Format :

[["abc","abc_15.0.1","Intital_phase","Tue Jul 26 21:00:00 2016","Thu Jul 28 09:00:00 2016"]]

Comment: Answer updated. It's definitively an issue with `d3.json` being an asynchronous call.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak makes total sense on what you say, could you give me an example of the same, I encounter another problem here after a callback as the value of taskArray is passed and is not initialized globally,  because i use the taskArray all over the code for other various manipulations, how do i work on that ?

Comment: You have to move all that code into a new function and pass it as callback. You cannot use the taskArray globally since it's fetched in background. If you struggle to reorganize the code, feel free to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think some commas need to be removed.
You don't need the one after the `endTime` attribute, and the one just before the closing `]`.

Comment: thanks for calrifying, @HubertGrzeskowiak. I wasn't sure.

Comment: while giving values statically it works, no issue with the comma, can you tell me whats the problem when i create the objects of the Array dynamically in the above example